# How to display custom block anywhere in a div?

Tags: theming, bootstrap-theme

I am creating one drupal 8 theme based on bootstrap framework, for banners I created one custom block, named as 'Homepage banner', without creating any region, how to display this on my homepage template 'page--front.html.twig'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Install the [twig tweak module](https://www.drupal.org/project/twig_tweak)
2. Insert the following code in your page--front.html.twig

   ```
   {{ drupal_entity('block_content', 1) }}
   ```

Where "1" is the block id. You can see the block ID when you edit the custom block, it's in the URL - E.g. my-drupal-site.com/block/1

Comment: Thanks @100pic, it worked :) :)